# My mocha/chai assert runs before the actual code

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mocha.js

I am trying to test a function but my assert statement always runs before my actual code. I'm testing the function createAppointment

My test:

```
  describe("Appointments", function() {
    it("should be able to create a new appointment", function(err) {
      let newAppts = [];

      testRequests.forEach(request => {
        createAppointment(testDb, request, function(err, id) {
          if (err) return err;
          newAppts.push(id);
          return id;
        });
      });

      assert.equal(newAppts.length, 5);
    });
  });
```

I am expecting the length of newAppts to be 5 but it returns 0 every time since the assert runs before the forEach is done. What is the best to to go about adding a callback?

Comment: Call `assert` inside the callback, I guess? However you have five requests total, so you should probably `await Promise.all(...)` Try this: https://pastebin.com/QhL1QYAp

Comment: @ChrisG it's giving me a timeout because done() isn't called. "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a test that works for me:

```
describe("Appointments", function () {
  it("should be able to create 5 new appointments", function (done) {

    // promisify createAppointment, build an array, pass to Promise.all()
    Promise.all(testRequests.map(request => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      createAppointment(testDb, request, function (err, id) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(id);
      });
    })))
    .then(newAppts => {
      // if all Promises resolve, check result
      assert.equal(newAppts.length, 5);
      // and tell mocha we're done
      done();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // if any one of the Promises fails, we're also done
      done(err);
    });

  });
});
```

If you simply want to test `async` code, it's enough to `return` the `Promise`. This will simply check if it resolves.
If your test is supposed to check the result though, don't return the Promise; instead use the `it` callback's `done` parameter to tell mocha that the async test has finished, after calling `assert` to check the result.